# How to calculate difference between two times which are fetched from parse in android

Tags: android

i am trying to calculate the difference between Completed Time and InProgressTime which are the two columns on parse

ParseObject object = list.get(i);

```
                         Date date = object.getDate("InProgressTime");
                        Log.e("From date",""+ date);

                        txtInprogress.setText(""+ date);
```

---

ParseObject object = list.get(i);

```
                        Date date = object.getDate("CompletedTime");
                        Log.e("From date",""+ date);

                        txtCompleted.setText(""+ date);
```

Comment: You should show us your code.

Comment: Show us the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will find different time in second

```
Date before = (Date) sdf.parse(mFirstDateTime);
Date now = new Date();
long diffTimeInMiliSecond = now.getTime() - before.getTime();
diffTimeInSecond = diffTimeInMiliSecond/1000;
```

Comment: i want difference in minuted

Comment: diffTimeInMinute = diffTimeInSecond/60;

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.currentTimeMillis()  on CompletedTime and InProgress. Then you calculate the difference

Comment: is there any need to convert the date format into String ??

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() return type long, to convert to String, you can write  txtCompleted.setText(""+ System.currentTimeMillis() );